# What do disruptors do?

Tags: splatoon

Disruptors are a type of subweapon that come in a set with certain main weapons. You throw them at other players and they disrupt them somehow.

But I can't find anything ingame that actually tells you what they *do* exactly.

How long does their effect last for, what does it do, and how big is their range?

Comment: Youtube has some nice videos of it in action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Splatoon wiki](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Disruptor) :

> Disruptor will not deal damage, but instead will lower the running speed, swimming speed, and ink recovery speed of rival squid.

The effect is significant and allows you to gain a real speed advantage over opponents. It lasts for approximately 5.15 seconds.

Comment: By how much? Is it a slight movement speed decrease or is it significant?

Comment: @Pyritie It's a significant decrease in movement speed. It makes moving through your own ink similar to moving through enemy ink.

Comment: And at least while they're uncommonly used, you usually get a lot of bonus advantage because the victim is trying to figure out why they're nerfed so bad. :)

Comment: A rejected edit suggested to use [Inkipedia](http://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Disruptor) instead of wikia.